# Spring JPA new insertion is not happening because of composite key

Tags: spring, database, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS", schema = "UR")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@IdClass(UserIdEntity.class)
public class UserEntity {
@SequenceGenerator(
name = "sequence_name",
sequenceName = "SEQ_USER_ID",
allocationSize = 1,
schema = "AR")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_USER_ID")
@Column(name = "USER_ID", length = 8,unique = true ,columnDefinition = "BIGINT" )
@NotNull
@Id
private BigInteger userId;
@Id
@Column(name = "USER_NUM")
@NotNull
private String userNum;
@Id
@Column(name = "USER_CD")
@NotNull
private String userCd;
@NotNull
@Column(name = "USER_ADDR")
private String userAddr;
}
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class UserIdEntity implements Serializable {
@NotNull
private BigInteger userId;
@Column(name = "USER_NUM" ,length = 5) @NotNull private String userNum;
@Column(name = "USER_CD",length = 5)  @NotNull private String userCd;
}
this is calling through service class
{userRepository.save(UserEntity)}
```

I am trying to insert the user records but its not happening  whereas update is happening without any concern
By doing some research it state that with JPA composite key there are some challenges while doing insertion,so some one please let me know what I am missing .everytime when i am debugging prepared statement while doing insertion its calling merge instead of save bcoz JPA take it as entity with update values instead of new insertion even though userId which is one  primary key out of 3   is null whereas rest 2 PK are having default values.I tried also passing transient variable to set userId  as new but no luck
`

```
your text
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing @NotNull annotation frome here

```
@NotNull
private BigInteger userId;
```

Because you have mention @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_USER_ID") for userId so it will assign value at run time. No need to mention @NotNull.

```
public class UserIdEntity implements Serializable {

private BigInteger userId;
@Column(name = "USER_NUM" ,length = 5) @NotNull private String userNum;
@Column(name = "USER_CD",length = 5)  @NotNull private String userCd;
}
```

Also, use @Transactional annotation on your service class.

Comment: Notnull removal I already tried but no success, but I marked service class as transactional as stated by you but it is still not passing.

Comment: when I am explicitly setting using this 
@Query(value = "select next value for U.SEQ_USER_ID from ( values 1 )", nativeQuery = true)
  Long getNextSequenceNumber(); and setting this value on id object its taking new insert but that is not optimal solution as I need sequence to be set implictly instead of setting by me .

Comment: Once remove this part of code @SequenceGenerator(
name = "sequence_name",
sequenceName = "SEQ_USER_ID",
allocationSize = 1,
schema = "AR")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_USER_ID") and add @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

Comment: yes, this is not of use with manually setting id but still it's not working with sequence generator.